# onItemInvoked doesn't fire on left click

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-metro

I'm using VS2013 RC and Win8.1 Pro Preview and have following problem:
In my JS-App i have a ListView with GridLayout.

```
 <div id="basicListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{
     itemDataSource : MusikSender.itemList.dataSource,
     itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate'),
     layout : {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout},
     selectionMode: 'none',
     swipeBehavior: 'none',
     tapBehavior: 'invoke'
     }">
    </div>
```

and fire it:

```
var dataArray = [
  { title: "Number1", text: "Number1", picture: "images/sender/number1.png" }
            ];

 var itemList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);

var publicMembers =
  {
    itemList: itemList
  };
WinJS.Namespace.define("MusikSender", publicMembers);

function itemInvokedHandler(eventObject) {
   eventObject.detail.itemPromise.done(function (invokedItem) {

     var title = invokedItem.data.title;

   });
 }

 document.querySelector('#basicListView').winControl.oniteminvoked = itemInvokedHandler;
```

i can't left click any items in the list. what's working: i can select them with arrow keys + return. Can't say anything about tap behaviour.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and set

```
selectionMode: 'none',
```

to

```
selectionMode: 'Single',
```

and let me know if it works.

also set

```
IsSwipeEnabled="true"
```

for setting touch gesture

Comment: unfortunately not :(
i ran a test-app from VS with ListView and it doesn't work either...

Comment: it will be listView.oniteminvoked = handler; not wincontrol

Comment: remove this two and see  selectionMode: 'none',
     swipeBehavior: 'none', guess you will be successfull now :)

Comment: if i define var listView = new WinJS.UI.ListView(document.getElementById("basicListView"));
the list disappears

Comment: Y would you define anything like that var listView = document.getElementById("basicListView") since this is listview already

Comment: document.getElementById("basicListView").addEventListner('iteminvoked', function(){ // do your stuff here}). and also remove selectionMode: 'none',
     swipeBehavior: 'none',

Comment: does the same thing. can it be possible, that it is a VS/Win bug or sth. like that?

Comment: No . Do some thing download this sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-ListView-essentials-d2ff764d and try run and see iteminvoke is happening or not

Comment: tapBehavior: 'invoke' change this to tapBehavior: 'invokeOnly'

Comment: if the sample does not work then it will finally be a vs bug try downlaoding the c# sample and see if it works .

Comment: works with c#. i'll reinstall VS and try it again. thanks for the help so far :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, this is the only way I could get it to work...

```
var myListView = document.getElementById("basicListView").winControl;
myListView.oniteminvoked = myEventHandler;

function myEventHandler(args) {
    var test = "Oh Hi";
}
```